# Is it possible to use HTC Desire C phone in Russia?

Tags: cellphones

I am hoping to be able to buy a prepaid SIM Card in Russia when travelling there, and use it for data/internet access with my current phone. Is that possible with the HTC Desire C Android phone (currently on a monthly plan from FIDO in Canada)?

Comment: Do you have an unlocked phone?

Answer (score 1):

Provided your phone is SIM-unlocked, you should get both GSM/2G and 3G service in Russia. [Fido will unlock your phone for $50](https://www.fido.ca/web/content/phonewarranty/fido_device_unlock), or you may be able to find [unsupported hacks](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2024422) on the Internet if you're willing to risk bricking the phone...

[This phone has all four world GSM bands](http://www.gsmarena.com/htc_desire_c-4759.php), so it can be used for 2G almost anywhere, and 900 and 2100 MHz 3G bands. [Russia uses the 2100 MHz 3G band](http://www.worldtimezone.com/gsm.html), so is compatible with the device.

Comment: I'm not too sure if unlocking your phone without permission from your carrier is completely legal.

Comment: @AdityaSomani It may void the warranty, but as far as I know it is not illegal to do so [in any country](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIM_lock). It may be illegal to _export_ unlocked phones in bulk for resale, though.